JTAG DR before IR?
I am using a jtag adapter (esp-prog) with an ESP32-D0WD dev board.  I am trying to understand why one tool chain works and another does not.  I am using a logic analyzer connected to the JTAG pins to observe flash upload.
The working toolchain begins its JTAG session with this sequence
select-dr-scan
select-ir-scan
capture-ir
shift-ir
shift-ir
exit1-ir
etc, for a 24-bit value

The failing toolchain begins its JTAG session with this sequence
select-dr-scan
capture-dr
shift-dr
shift-dr
etc, for a 67 bit value

The failing toolchain receives all 1's in that DR-shift.  It aborts, complains about all-ones, and suggests I have wiring errors.
As the undisturbed hardware setup works with a different toolchain (for both upload and debugging), I am quite skeptical of that suggestion.
My newbie research on JTAG operation finds statements that suggest that a JTAG instruction is needed to select "which" data.  That makes sense to a software guy like me, and a reason for getting all-ones out of the data register operations without a preceding instruction register sequence.
Am I on the right track?  Is an instruction needed before expecting good info from a shift-dr?  If not, what data would be expected?

If both toolchains operate with same hardware, this seems like a configuration problem. Could you be more specific about each toolchain and respective configurations ?

The toolchain that works is from platformIO, the failing toolchain is the VisualMicro plugin to VisualStudio.
